# how to download zip file from aws s3 using terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

i am working on terraform,i am facing issue in  download the zip file from s3 to local using terraform.
creating the lambda function using zip file. Can any one please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the [aws_s3_bucket_object data_source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/s3_bucket_object.html). This allows you to download the contents of an s3 bucket. Sample code snippet is shown below:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "secret_key" {
    bucket = "awesomecorp-secret-keys"
    key    = "awesomeapp-secret-key"
}

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
## ...

provisioner "file" {
    content = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.secret_key.body}"
 }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. if i want to latest version of zip or jar file, how to call the latest file from s3

Comment: `aws_s3_bucket_object` doesn't work when the file is a zip. Only if it's JSON or plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to create a lamdba function using a file in an S3 Bucket you can simply reference it in your ressource  :

```
resource aws_lambda_function lambda {
  function_name = "my_function"

  s3_bucket = "some_bucket"
  s3_key    = "lambda.zip"

...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. if i want to latest version of zip or jar file, how to  call the latest file from s3

Comment: If you enabled versionning on your bucket, by default AWS will give you the latest version of an object

Comment: I have little bit confusion, please find below syntax                                                         
s3_bucket = "new_bucket"
s3_key    = "Job_name/folder_name/target/latest.zip" In S3 key having job name, foldername ,taget and zip file . So in this scenario how to get latest version of zip file

Comment: How are you putting the zip file in your s3 bucket ?

Comment: Actually we are doing continous integreation with CodeBuild and storing the artifacts push automatically in to s3. Now S3 key having job name, foldername ,taget and zip file.

Comment: Ok and after each build you are replacing the old file ?

Comment: No.. If u click on show, it will show date wise and latest version